# php sql insert work only for the first column

Tags: php, sql

I'm making a php connection tomysql database and everything is ok, only my insert statement fill just the first column of database the other remains null.
Cannot undestad where the problem is. This page is the post.php and i use to store data in database.

```
  <?php
  session_start();
  $username = $_POST['user'];
  $password = $_POST['pass'];
  $gender = $_POST['gen'];
  $conn = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root','Ferolux1!','chat');
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO login(Name,Password,Gender) VALUES (?,?,?)");
  $stmt->bind_param("sss", $username,$password,$gender);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $password);
  $stmt->execute();
  mysqli_close($conn);
 ?>
```

This is the script in signup.php, the page where is the form that send data to the post.php.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $("#submitButton").click(function(){
         var username = $("#username").val();
         var password = $("#password").val();
         var ele = document.getElementsByName('gender');
            for(i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
                if(ele[i].checked)
                gender = ele[i].value;
            }
         $.post("post.php", {user : username});
         $.post("post.php", {pass: password});
         $.post("post.php", {gen: gender});
         setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = "http://localhost/Chat2/home.php";}, 500);
         //window.location.href = "http://localhost/Chat2/home.php";
         return false;
       });
     </script>
```

I'm sure that the $_POST variables are not null. So why my insert only fill the name column?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use 3 different calls to `$.post()`. You have to send them all in the same call.

And instead of `setTimeout()`, do the redirect in the AJAX callback function.

```
$.post("post.php", {
    user: username,
    pass: password,
    gen: gender
}, function() {
    window.location.href="http://localhost/Chat2/home.php";
});
```

In your method, the first call just inserted the username with empty password and gender, the second call inserts the password with empty username and gender, and the third call inserts the gender with empty username and password.

Also, if you want the gender more simply, you can write:

```
var gender = $("[name=gender]:checked").val()
```